# When will be released Kubernetes CronJob stable version from betav1

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I am using Kubernetes cron job to some scheduling , i can see kubernetes cron job still in beta version
I am using the Kubernetes version: v1.16.0
Please suggest me on this is fine to go with v1beta1 version  for production ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the issue that tracks this effort: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/82659 No timeline at this point.

It's fine to go with v1beta1 version for production. As you can read here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/#api-versioning, beta level "code is well tested. Enabling the feature is considered safe. Enabled by default"

Answer (score 1):

By now it has reached general availability as stated in a [blogpost about Kubernetes 1.21](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/09/kubernetes-release-1.21-cronjob-ga/).